# <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="" Inherits="" %>

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to run my application, it gives me error:

```
Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and 
that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
```

please tell me the use of this inherits parameter in this tag?

Comment: You mean you're deliberately leaving it empty? Can you try omitting it entirely? It's used to make the generated class for your page inherit from a different base-class that you've provided, which must itself inherit from Page. [`@Page` directive reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) (which oddly seems to have gone away in later .NET documentation?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the CodeFileBaseClass attribute, which should point to your baseclass.

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Inherits="University.AspNet.Index" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" CodeFileBaseClass="XXXXXX" %>
```

- **CodeFileBaseClass**
  Specifies a path to a base class for a page and its associated code-behind class. This attribute is optional, but when it is used the **CodeFile** attribute must also be present.